# Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, android-support-library, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a movie video trailer via youtubeAPI but when I added YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip in dependancies it shows that error:

> Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: MyMovies/app\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip.

So How can I solve it. or how to add zip file in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip` file > go into `libs` directory. You will find `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar`. Try to include that in your project.